# Python: Getting the user's country automatically?

Tags: python, geolocation

There's probably an easy way to do this with some API, but web programming is not my forte.  **How can I figure out the user's country in Python?**  I need to use an OS-agnostic solution, and I'd prefer to only have to use the standard library.  Is there something I can do with IP addresses, maybe?

Comment: you will need an ip table ... that denotes geographic regions for various ip ranges ... or use an API and do a json call or rpc call to said api..maybe something like http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

Comment: @JoranBeasley Is right. I would use a service to do that. This service suggested here also as a python library that you could use: 
https://github.com/sonicrules1234/pyipinfodb/blob/master/pyipinfodb.py

Comment: Joran, that's exactly what I need!  Thank you!  Shame I can't accept comments, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Joran Beasely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541038/joran-beasley) gave a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589993/python-getting-the-users-country-automatically#comment18627121_13589993), but since it came in the form of a comment rather than a reply I can't mark it as my accepted answer.  Still, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

> How can I figure out the user's country in Python?

Getting a user's country information from their IP address is pretty straightforward with IPinfo.

> I need to use an OS-agnostic solution, and I'd prefer to only have to use the standard library.

Even though it is far easier to use IPinfo with [Python Module](https://github.com/ipinfo/python) or calling [API](https://ipinfo.io/developers) via the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library, you can still get the IP geolocation data through the standard libraries. You have to use the `urllib.request` and `json` library for this purpose, which comes standard with Python installation.

**Follow the instructions:**

```py
# no need to pip install anything
from urllib.request import urlopen  # to make the request to the API
import json # to parse the API response

# declare your IP Address here
ip_address = "8.8.8.8"

# get your token from IPinfo's account dashboard
token = ""

# create the url for the API, using f-string
url = f"https://www.ipinfo.io/{ip_address}?token={token}"

# call the API and save the response
with urlopen(url) as response:
    response_content = response.read()

# parsing the response 
data = json.loads(response_content)

print(data)
```

This `data` here is a Python Dictionary object, that looks like this:

```py
{'anycast': True,
 'city': 'Mountain View',
 'country': 'US',
 'hostname': 'dns.google',
 'ip': '8.8.8.8',
 'loc': '37.4056,-122.0775',
 'org': 'AS15169 Google LLC',
 'postal': '94043',
 'region': 'California',
 'timezone': 'America/Los_Angeles'}
```

Now you can get any value from the `data` variable, like so:

```py
print(data['country'])  # Output: 'US'
print(data['city'])  # Output: 'Mountain View'

# loc stands for location.
print(data['loc'])  # Output: '37.4056,-122.0775'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use geo-ip for Python:
http://code.google.com/p/python-geoip/
It's default free database is good enough to get users' country with good accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the public IP of the user then you can do so by using [freegeip](https://freegeoip.net/). Below is the Python 3.4.2 code for getting location and time zone.

```
>>> import requests
>>> ip = '141.70.111.66'
>>> url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/'+ip
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> js = r.json()
>>> js['country_code']
'DE'
>>> js['country_name']
'Germany'
>>> js['time_zone']
'Europe/Berlin'
>>> js['city']
'Stuttgart'
>>> js.items()
dict_items([('latitude', 48.7667), ('ip', '141.70.111.66'), ('region_code', 'BW'), ('country_code', 'DE'), ('city', 'Stuttgart'), ('zip_code', '70173'), ('country_name', 'Germany'), ('longitude', 9.1833), ('region_name', 'Baden-Württemberg Region'), ('time_zone', 'Europe/Berlin'), ('metro_code', 0)])
```